# Is there any javascript translater which can convert SVG to VML and VML to SVG?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, svg, vml

I have some file written in SVG, I want my javascript code can convert the SVG to VML if it detect the user's browser is IE8, 
Is it possible? Many thanks!

Comment: is there any reason to do this in JS?

Comment: yes, I want to draw something, and want to make it compatible for IE8

Comment: I don't see why you have to do this on the *client side*.

Answer (score 0):

There are javascript libraries that will generate VML or SVG automatically depending on what the browser supports, but only if you use that library's methods for creating the svg.

[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com) is probably the most well-known one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, svg2vml.js - http://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/
Works well for SVG images.

They are still working on adding svg DOM support for dynamic svg creation and manipulation programatically via js.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the work in progress? It seems that svg2vml hasn't been updated in the past 3 years!